# How to redirect to different Url when button is click?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a form

```
 <form id="Print" action="/Order/Print" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" target="_blank">
   ...

     <div>
         <button onclick="window.location.pathname = '<%= Url.Action("Edit", "Order", new {id = Model.Order.ID}) %>'">Cancel</button>
         <button onclick="getReport('print')"> Print</button>
     </div>
</form>
```

I want to redirect to `/Order/Edit/XXX` page when I click on `Cancel button`. Right now it is taking me to `/Order/Print` page.

How can I redirect to `/Order/Edit/123` page when I click cancel button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your form action method is overriding your button action method. You can use jquery click event like below.

```
$(document).read(function () {

    $("#btnId").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = '@Url.Action("Edit", "Order", new { id = "ID" })';
        window.location.href = url;
        });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your form submit button will be calling a controller method

then in your method

```
poblic ActionResult Yourmethod()
{
//after your operations

return RedirectToAction("controllerName", ActionName, parameter if any);
 //this methods will load a different view from a differnt controller

}
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response. Is it the only way I can redirect to different Url. FYI, I have modified my questions. There are more buttons to be submit in that form.

Comment: You can just wrap your button with an anchor link giving the url in anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

add a semi-colon after the pathname you're setting, then add return false; to prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. I have a couple more buttons to submit the form.